# VBA involving multiple checkboxes on one sheet

Tags: vba, excel, checkbox

I currently have the following code in one of my sheets below.

The way it is set up:

- A6:A35 all populate a TRUE or FALSE value based on the checkmark in Column F of the corresponding row.
- If F6 is checked, A6 is TRUE .. and FALSE when unchecked.
- Column B contents never change.. they are simply numbering the rows on the sheet.

The code I have that's working right now is only setup to work on one line of the sheet.. my thought was get the code working first then expand it to the rest of the sheet.  Basically now that it all works and functions the way I wanted it to for row 6.. I want it to work independently on each row from Row 6 to Row 35.

My question: **How do I make it look at each row, so no matter which row a checkbox is checked it goes through the cycle of events, as well as how to list the check box names for each box since there are 30 different boxes?**

I hope this makes sense .. sorry if my code is really ugly .. its pieced together from lots of reading online and is working exactly how I want it to on Row 6 .. now if I can get it to work the same way from Row 6 to Row 35 ill be delighted!

```
Sub Checkbox_Uncheck()

    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Range("A6") = True Then
        Response = MsgBox("Are you finished with the keyfob programmer?", vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

        If Response = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "Finish scheduled programming before selecting the completed checkbox!", vbInformation
            Worksheets("Sign Up Sheet").CheckBoxes("Check Box 32").Value = xlOff
        Else
            'Call Reload_financials
        End If
    Else
    End If

    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)


    '   Find last row
    myLastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '   Loop through range
    For i = 6 To myLastRow
        If Cells(i, "A").Value = True Then Range(Cells(i, "C"), Cells(i, "E")).ClearContents

        Worksheets("Sign Up Sheet").CheckBoxes("Check Box 32").Value = xlOff
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why is "Check Box 32" on row 6?  And what are the names of your other 29 checkboxes? Is there any logic to the way they are named, so that we could program aroudn that? If not, I would suggest renaming them from 6 to 35, so that they easily coincide with the related row.

Comment: In `Checkbox_Uncheck` you can use `Application.Caller` to get the name of the clicked checkbox - from that you can either extract the row from the name (if you follow @DavidZemens suggestion) or get the `TopLeftCell.Row` of the checkbox's `Shape` on the sheet (assuming your checkboxes are correctly located entirely within each row).

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Checkbox_Uncheck()
    Dim cbName as string, rw as long
    Dim Response As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim sht as WorkSheet

    Set sht = ActiveSheet
    cbName = Application.Caller 'name of triggering checkbox

    'as suggested by David Z,rename your checkboxes as "cbRow_x" where x=row number
    rw = CLng(Replace(cbName,"cbRow_",""))


    If sht.Cells(rw, "A") = True Then
        Response = MsgBox("Are you finished with the keyfob programmer?", _
                     vbQuestion + vbYesNo)

        If Response = vbNo Then
            MsgBox "Finish scheduled programming before selecting" & _
                   " the completed checkbox!", vbInformation
            sht.CheckBoxes(cbName).Value = xlOff
        Else
            'Call Reload_financials
        End If
    Else
    End If

    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim i As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1)


    '   Find last row
    myLastRow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    '   Loop through range
    For i = 6 To myLastRow
        If sht.Cells(i, "A").Value = True Then 
           sht.Range(sht.Cells(i, "C"), sht.Cells(i, "E")).ClearContents
        End If

        sht.CheckBoxes("cbRow_" & i).Value = xlOff
    Next i

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```